# Equivalent of fetch_token with auth_code in httr2 library

Tags: python, r, oauth-2.0, httr, httr2

I want to replicate **python** example of receiving both access and refresh tokens, like here **(Python)**

```py
token_response = oauth2_session.fetch_token(TOKEN_GRANT_URL, code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET)
```

How could I do it using `httr2` library?

There are my previous steps to get the `AUTHORIZATION_CODE` **(R)**

```
client <- httr2::oauth_client(token_url = token_grant_url,secret = .app_secret,id = .app_key)
url_to_browse <- httr2::oauth_flow_auth_code_url(client=client, auth_url = auth_url,
                                                 scope = paste0(SCOPES_TO_REQUEST, collapse = " "),
                                                 redirect_uri = .client_redirect,state = STATE)
```

But I don't understand which function should I use instead of `fetch_token`

Thanks for any help you can provide

Also I leave [the link](https://github.com/r-lib/httr2/issues/151) of my issue from github page of `httr2` project

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `oauth2.0_token` function (https://httr.r-lib.org/reference/oauth2.0_token.html)

```
token <- oauth2.0_token(
  endpoint,
  app,
  scope = NULL,
  user_params = NULL,
  type = NULL,
  use_oob = getOption("httr_oob_default"),
  oob_value = NULL,
  as_header = TRUE,
  use_basic_auth = FALSE,
  cache = getOption("httr_oauth_cache"),
  config_init = list(),
  client_credentials = FALSE,
  credentials = NULL,
  query_authorize_extra = list()
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this function, but there is no `auth_code` in parameters.
Besides, I'm not sure whether it's appropriate solution to take a function from other libraries. It would be great to find solution using `httr2`

Comment: Ahh I see,, my bad, totally missed the 2. I guess the equivalent is the `oauth_flow_auth_code` function. which then returns an `oauth_token`  https://httr2.r-lib.org/reference/oauth_flow_auth_code.html?q=oauth_flow_auth_code Maybe this helps

Comment: I am using `oauth_flow_auth_code_url`, it helps me to generate AUTHORIZATION_CODE, but then I need to receive refresh/access tokens